# What is good pattern to share an object between modules in Nodejs?

Tags: node.js

My situation is that I'm working with Websocket, and there is only one websocket server and lot of methods need to get data from server and modify things on server, i.e. delete inactive sockets, etc.

Right now I'm simply passing server instance through function calls and wrapper functions which is getting tedious and is error prone to everything (cyclic dependencies, typos, etc)

Importing server instance causes circular dependencies.

Passing them through parameters causes too much interdependence.

Ex:

```
onConnection -> attaches events 

onMessage = msgHanlder(server);
...
```

then in msgHandler there are multiple events to take care of

```
onNewMsg = newMsg(server)
onDelete = delete(server)
onRequest = request(server)
```

It's very functional style programming but it's too much pain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a caching module ( get,set method ) and require this module to manage your state between different modules.

cache.js

```
let _cache = {};
module.exports = {
  "get":function(key){
     return _cache[key];
   },
  "set":function(key,value){
     _cache[key] = value;
    }
}
```

a.js

```
const cache = require('./cache');
const b = require('./b');
cache.set('a','value set in a');
b.invoke();
```

b.js

```
const cache = require('./cache');
module.exports = {
  "invoke":function(){
      console.log("Module A: ",cache.get('a')); 
   }
}
```